# New Expression Requires (), [], or {} after type

Tags: c#, asp.net

Anybody see what's going on with the code below. I'm trying to dynamically create LinkButtons with dynamic Text and ID values from the database.

```
        rptHeadline.DataSource = ds;

        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton


        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0) {

        lb.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["URL"].ToString();
        lb.ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["URL"].ToString();

        }

        rptHeadline.DataBind();
```

Comment: missing semicolon and probably ctor arguments

Comment: What do you think this is? JavaScript?

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript either..

Comment: @Daniel - JavaScript allows you to omit the parentheses from a new expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement `LinkButton lb = new LinkButton` is incomplete. You need to add `();` to call the default constructor.

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the following:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton
```

Should be:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
```

Not sure if LinkButton needs arguments though!

Answer (score 0):

Missing a semicolon and parens here:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
```